# How to present subarray values into cells of a table using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I've already search it, but unfortunately didn't find any satisfactory solution to my problem.

I have following array with some subarrays:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        ([0] => AAAA
         [1] => BBBB
         [2] => CCCC
         [3] => DDDD
         [4] => EEEE
         [5] => FFFF
         [6] => GGGG)
    [1] => Array
        ([0] => hhhh
         [1] => iiii
         [2] => jjjj
         [3] => kkkk
         [4] => llll
         [5] => mmmm
         [6] => nnnn)

    ...

    [999] => Array
        ([0] => OOOO
         [1] => PPPP
         [2] => QQQQ
         [3] => RRRR
         [4] => SSSS
         [5] => TTTT
         [6] => UUUU)
)
```

Then with the following code I'm able to present it into a table:

```
$table = '<table border=1>';
    // Select values of the array to create table.
    foreach($array as $key => $row){
        $table .= '<tr>';

        foreach($row as $value){
            $table .= '
                <td>'.$value.'</td>
            ';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
```

The graphical result is something like this:

```
AAAA | BBBB | CCCC | DDDD | EEEE | FFFF | GGGG
hhhh | iiii | jjjj | kkkk | llll | mmmm | nnnn
...
OOOO | PPPP | QQQQ | RRRR | SSSS | TTTT | UUUU
```

But as I would like to manipulate some of the cells of the table inserting for example a link in some of them I'm looking for a way that would allow me to do this:

```
        foreach($??? ??? $???){
            $table .= '
                <td>'.$value[0].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[2].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[3].'</td>
                <td>'.$value[4].'</td>
                <td><a href="#">'.$value[5].'</a></td>
            ';
        }
```

Anybody has an idea how I could manage to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
//...
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 5) {
        $value = '<a href="#">'.$value.'</a>';
    }

    $table .= '
        <td>'.$value.'</td>
    ';
}
//...
```

The [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct can assign the current element's key to a variable.

Comment: Nice and simple!
Although we should avoid comments like this I must say thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what factors cause you to generate the link.  If it's simply the 6th value in each array, then @undefined's solution will work.  If it's something you manually control, perhaps an approach like this will do the trick for you:

First, define the elements you want linked as keyed arrays themselves:

```
$array = array(
    array('AAAA', array('text' => 'BBBB', 'href' => 'http://stackoverflow.com'), 'CCCC', 'DDDD', 'EEEE', 'FFFF', 'GGGG'),
    array('hhhh', 'iiii', 'jjjj', array('text' => 'kkkk', 'href' => 'http://stackoverflow.com'), 'llll', 'mmmm', 'nnnn')
);
```

Then, when you process each element in the array, use [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) to check and see if it's an array itself, and process it differently:

```
$table = '<table border=1>';
// Select values of the array to create table.
foreach($array as $key => $row){
    $table .= '<tr>';

    foreach($row as $value){
        // PROCESS ARRAY AS A LINK
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $value = '<a href="' . $value['href'] . '">' . $value['text'] . '</a>';
        }

        $table .= '
            <td>'.$value.'</td>
        ';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
```